# Is it necessary to removed an unwanted tag from the questions before to ask for its burnination?

Tags: support, blocked-tags

I notice that here on Meta Stack Overflow, when somebody asks for black-listing a tag, sometimes a developer will reply saying the tag has been black-listed. That answer seems given indifferently from the number of questions using that tag.

Does that mean removing the tag from the question is not necessary for the tag to be black-listed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a very bad user experience if a tag remains on a question after it has been blacklisted - the next editor will see his edit fail unless he proactively removes it.

"Burnination" is slang for "tag deletion" - it simply involves removing all occurrences of a tag from all questions on the site. Users can do this by editing, and developers can do it by re-writing history.

"Blacklisting" is the addition of a rule that prevents a term from being used on the site. There are tag blacklists and general-purpose blacklists.

Burnination is fairly common. Blacklisting is fairly rare. But when a term *is* blacklisted, it will nearly always be burninated first.

Comment: I got it. So, when a developer says the tag has been burninated, s/he means the history has been rewritten to remove the tag. Why isn't the same done when a request for a black-list has been done, and the request is up-voted from X users? I can understand developers cannot decide all the times when a request for black-listing is correct, but what would be done if "drupal" were not black-listed on Drupal Answers, and there were 200 questions using it?

Comment: There are a few reasons for why we're reluctant to blacklist *anything*, but the most important one here pertains to blacklisting things that are *in frequent use*. If you consider each use to be a vote in favor of the tag, then it takes quite a few votes on a meta post to override that... So the better discussion to have first is *always* "should this tag exist?" - if it is decided that the tag should be removed, and it is, and it's persistently restored... *Then* there's an argument for blacklisting. Or synonymizing.

Comment: The last question is then "When can you (impersonal you) say it has been decided the tag should be removed?" `:)`